# How to change the value of int elements in series

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, series

I want to change only `int` elements in this series.
I want to print `str` values unchanged and print square values of all `int` elements.
Why doesn't it work?

```
ser3=pd.Series([100,'bulya',300,'asya'], ['tom','bob','cat','foot']) 
print(ser3) 
for i in ser3.iloc[[]]:
    if type(ser3.iloc[i]) == str:
        print (ser3.iloc[[i]])
    else:
        print (ser3.iloc[[i]]**2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.Series.apply` with a custom function.

```
ser3 = pd.Series([100,'bulya',300,'asya'], ['tom','bob','cat','foot'])

res = ser3.apply(lambda x: x**2 if isinstance(x, int) else x)

print(res)

tom     10000
bob     bulya
cat     90000
foot     asya
dtype: object
```

---

However, in my opinion this is a misuse of Pandas. I recommend you restructure your data so that numeric data is held in a numeric series. You will then able to perform operations in a vectorised fashion.

For example, to extract only the squares of numbers, you can use `pd.to_numeric` followed by `dropna`:

```
res = pd.to_numeric(ser3, errors='coerce').dropna()**2

print(res)

tom    10000.0
cat    90000.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get at the sub-series by mapping `type` and testing equality with `int`.  Then filter and square.

```
ser3.loc[ser3.map(type) == int] ** 2

tom    10000
cat    90000
dtype: object
```

You can then update the series with the `update` method.

```
ser3.update(ser3.loc[ser3.map(type) == int] ** 2)
ser3

tom     10000
bob     bulya
cat     90000
foot     asya
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

**`to_numeric`** with **`fillna`**

```
(pd.to_numeric(df, errors='coerce')**2).fillna(df)

tom     10000
bob     bulya
cat     90000
foot     asya
dtype: object
```